# Log into git server with ssh key

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

This is a simple question as i have only ever used github repositories previously.

How do i log into a git server with my ssh key?

The server example is git.website.com and i am told that "you should be able to log in to this server using your SSH key".  When i go to the example git.website.com website  it asks for an email and password, not an ssh key.

I assume there is either a cli or other software i can use.

Thank you to anyone answering as i know this is a 101 question. thank you in advance.

Everything I look up online discusses setting up a git server website, but for me the server was already set up years ago, apparently my ssh key was just added to the server so that i can log in, I just do not know how.

I expected there to be some interface where you put in your ssh key and then are allowed into the server.

Comment: There's nothing Git-specific about using ssh; and most commercial Git hosting services don't let you log in in the first place, so this particular form of the question is peculiar at best. Some number of organizations provide their own "corporate service" as it were, which may include both logins *and* Git service, and there the question does make sense, sort of. It depends heavily on the organization.

Comment: To put it another way: what exactly are you trying to do here? Set up your own Git hosting service?

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal or git bash, you ssh into the server like so:

`ssh username@server`

Your key should be associated with the username on that server, and if the keys match you'll be logged in.

More info:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection